# I cant seem to remove the white on the top of my PNG when i use scroll in background attachment

Tags: html, css

That green picture is saved as PNG but when i use the background-attachment:scroll the white thing appeard

[image]

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parallax1 {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(../imgs/slide1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 1080px;
}

.about {
  background-image: url("../../../../Desktop/tipfinal/images/bg1.png");
  background-attachment: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 500px;
}

.parallax2 {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-image: url("../../../../Desktop/tipfinal/images/bg2.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 1080px;
}

.parallax2 h1 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Initiative PH</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax1">
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>IAbout me details</p>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax2">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>about me details</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hi! I am doing a simple website for my class. I wanted to explore the use of parallax. However, i am having some problem with it.

when i use `background-attachment: scroll;` the transparent part of my background was replaced by a solid white color.

How can i remove that white thing on my png pictures. I am trying to do a background cover parallax.

Comment: who told you it's replaced in the image ? i am sure it's simply the body background and you see it because the image is transparent

Answer (score 0):

Like Temani Afif said, he was right it was not the image it is the body background color.

I think the solution is to reduce the distance between the green thing and the images. So it will looks like attached to each other.

Try this

```
    .parallax2{
    position:absolute;
    padding-top: 980px; //adjust this yourself
    }
```

Comment: got it thanks for this. however, i tried doing what you suggested but i can still see the body background

Comment: @jimi you will always see the background. what did you excpect ? you will always see something since you image is transparent, it's logic no ?

Comment: @jimi see my edited code. But adjust the position yourself, because you didn't provide simplified code and other element for me to fix